# Regex to parse out substring, two options

Tags: regex, parsing

I have a list of group names that all either contain prod or nonprod inside of the name. I would like to extract out the prod or nonprod from the group name for each row. Is there a regex that could do this?

Group name examples:

- eap-edp-refined-nonprod-adp
- eap-edp-reporting-prod-gcp
- eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod-lunar
- eap-edp-ingestion-prod-google

I would just want to extract prod/nonprod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((?:non)?prod)

(       = Start of capture group
(?:non) = None capturing group for the literal string "non"
?       = Zero or one of "non"
prod    = The literal string "prod"
)       = End of capture group
```

Try it out at https://regex101.com/